# python statsmodel seasonal_decompose Error with “len() of unsized object”

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: date & count.  and i am trying to use seasonal_decompose in statsmodel to visualize the time series analysis

```
df_counts_outlier_trim=df_counts_outlier[['date', 'count']]

df_counts_outlier_trim.set_index('date', inplace=True) # set yyyy-mm-dd as index

print (df_counts_outlier_trim.info())
```

returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 179 entries, 2018-01-21 to 2018-07-18
Data columns (total 1 columns):
count    179 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 2.8+ KB

print (df_counts_outlier_trim)
```

returns

```
            count
date             
2018-01-21     48
2018-01-22    304
2018-01-23    368
2018-01-24    528
2018-01-25    448
2018-01-26    304
2018-01-27    256
2018-01-28    272
2018-01-29    448
2018-01-30    480
2018-01-31    464
2018-02-01    448
2018-02-02    208
2018-02-03    288
2018-02-04    352
```

Now I try statsmodels seasonal_decompose:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

result = seasonal_decompose(df_counts_outlier_trim.count, model='additive', freq=1)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "outliers.py", line 217, in <module>
    result = seasonal_decompose(df_counts_outlier_trim.count, model='additive', freq=1)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/waypoint_benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py", line 70, in seasonal_decompose
    nobs = len(x)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

This is driving me crazy and cannot find a solution.  Does any guru have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the limited set of data that you provide, I was able to run the code with the following modification.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
result = seasonal_decompose(df_counts_outlier_trim.count.values, model='additive', freq=1)
```

notice the **`values`** in the line. I have tested this in python 2.7.